# How to get real class instance name from a vector?

Tags: c++, c++11, inheritance, vector, c++14

I have class:

```
class IComponent{};
```

And I use it like base class for other specific classes.

```
class First : public IComponent{public: void First();};   
class Second : public IComponent{public: void Second();};
```

And I have a class Object that have a vector that stores classes inherited from IComponent.

```
vector<IComponent*> vectorOfComponents;
```

In this class i have a template method that adds component to vector.

```
template<typename comp>
void AddComponent() {
    comp * c = new comp();
    getComponents().push_back(c);
}
```

But I want also to have possibility to get components of specific type, so I created that method:

```
template<typename comp>
comp * GetComponent()
{
    comp component;
    for (int i = 0; i < GetComponentsCount(); i++)
        if (typeid(*getComponents()[i]).name() == typeid(component).name())
            return (comp*)getComponents()[i];
    return NULL;
}
```

And when I later run it:

```
    if (obj.GetComponent<FirstClass>() != NULL)
        std::cout << "isn't null\n";
    else
        std::cout << "is null\n";
```

I know that vector saves pushed instances of IComponent inherited class, but it always prints me is null, because first typeid() shows me IComponent, and second shows me specific inherited component.

How to get a specific type from a vector? I tried polymorphism but that don't work, or I do something wrong:

```
template<typename comp>
void AddComponent() {
    comp c = comp();
    IComponent * i = &c;
    getComponents().push_back(i);
}
```

Comment: You could add a pure virtual function to `IComponent` that returns a ID. Derived classes then are forced to implement that function so you can ask them for their type.

Comment: It is interesting that you think this has anything to do with vectors. Types and objects don't change their characteristics by virtue of being stored in a vector.

Comment: @juanchopanza Types implementing ownership are able to implement polymorphism. For example `shared_ptr` works with the dynamic type of its object even when it's narrowed to a non-polymorphic base pointer. Also the question mentions compile-time, template polymorphism. Long story short… polymorphism in C++ is big, noodly, and complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`typeid` only works dynamically for polymorphic class types. For a class to be polymorphic, it needs a `virtual` function. Also, the destructor must be `virtual` if a class object may be owned by a base-class pointer, which may be the case here.

So, you should use,

```
class IComponent{
    virtual ~ IComponent() = default;
};
```

**Edit:** also, `type_info::name()` returns a C string pointer, which is not comparable using `==`. A program using dynamic libraries may observe identical `name` strings at different addresses (though otherwise it's unusual). Compare the `type_info` objects instead. Also, `typeid` can take a type as an operand; you don't need to create an object to use it. So, you can do,

```
if (typeid(*getComponents()[i]) == typeid(comp))
```

Note that this checks for an exactly matching type. To find derived objects as well (permitting `comp` to be a base class), use `dynamic_cast`:

```
if (comp *p = dynamic_cast<comp *>(getComponents()[i])) {
    return p;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you consider another possible workaround.

So you might add a function `getType` into the base class:

```
enum class Types {
    First,
    Second
};

class IComponent {
    public:
        virtual Types getType() const = 0;
        virtual ~IComponent() = default;
};
```

And then implement it in derived classes:

```
class First : public IComponent {
public:
    virtual Types getType() const override {
        return Types::First;
    }
};

class Second : public IComponent {
    public:
        virtual Types getType() const override {
            return Types::Second;
        }
};
```

After that searching and other tasks seems to be pretty easy:

```
const auto it = std::find_if(std::cbegin(components), std::cend(components),
    [](auto& ptr) {
        return ptr->getType() == Types::Second;
    }
);
```

[**wandbox example**](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/50gtVwWl33ShQQn5)

Comment: Wow, that code looks great, can you explain me what is enum class? Is it enum that contains type?

And whats mean const = 0?
"virtual Types getType() const = 0;"
That the function is pure virtual and it does not affect class instance fields?
And whats mean:
"const override" ?

Comment: @Michael Oops, seems that you aren't familiar enough with C++, at least with C++11/14. Definitely you can easily google each of these features. Comments are too short to explain them all :)

Comment: Ok, thanks. I would give you upwote, but I don't have much reputation. :D

Comment: @Michael It doesn't matter at all :)

Comment: @Michael To help you research those features... 1) `enum class` is a _scoped enum_ (a.k.a. a "strongly-typed enum"); all of its member names are in its scope, and don't implicitly convert to `int`.  2) `getType()` is a _pure virtual_ function; `= 0` means that any subclasses have to implement `getType()` themselves.  3) `const` after the parameter list, used for _const correctness_, means that the function can't affect instance fields, yes; specifically, it means that `this` is `const`.  4) The _`override` specifier_ indicates that the function is virtual and overrides a base class function.

Comment: @EdgarRokyan Thanks.  Figured I'd give him the relevant search terms so it'd be easier to find more information, and a short description to act as a starting point.

Comment: @JustinTime Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `IComponent` has at least one `virtual` method (the destructor will suffice,  which should be virtual anyway when dealing with inheritance) and then use `dynamic_cast` instead of `typeid`.

```
class IComponent{
public:
    virtual ~IComponent() = default;
};

template<typename ComponentType>
ComponentType* GetComponent()
{
    auto &comps = getComponents();
    for (auto *item : comps) {
        ComponentType *comp = dynamic_cast<ComponentType*>(item);
        if (comp)
            return comp;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```